# Create custom finder with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I trying to implement a database with a many-to-many relationship.The database has been built, now we need queries to it. I'm using this article as an example: https://www.bezkoder.com/jpa-many-to-many/. When I create custom finder in Repository - server crushes at running.

I have two Entity: MassageEntity and RstringsEntity. I'm trying to create a method `List<MasageEntity> findMasageEntitiesByRstringsEntitiesId(Long string_id);`. Without that method server starts.

This is what the error looks like.

```
2022-04-09 22:08:39.091 ERROR 9672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'massegeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Massage_repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'massage_repo' defined in Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at Dyplom.rString.RStringApplication.main(RStringApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'massage_repo' defined in Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List Dyplom.rString.repository.massage_repo.findMassageentByRstringsentsId(java.lang.Long)! No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'rstringsentsId' found for type 'Masageent'!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Now i show some code.

RstringEntity.java

```
package Dyplom.rString.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "string")
public class RstringsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "string_massage",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "string_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),  },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "massage_id",referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<MasageEntity> massagess = new HashSet<>();


    public RstringsEntity(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public RstringsEntity() {
    }

    // getters and setters
    public void addMassage(MasageEntity massage) {
        this.massagess.add(massage);
        massage.getMassages().add(this);
    }

    public void removeMassage(long mId) {
        MasageEntity massage = this.massagess.stream().filter(t -> t.getId() == mId).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (massage != null) this.massagess.remove(massage);
        massage.getMassages().remove(this);
    }
    /*
        @ManyToMany()
        private List<rStringsMassageEntity> massages;
    */

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

MassageEntity.java

```
package Dyplom.rString.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "massages")
public class MasageEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "string_text")
    private String string_text;
    @Column(name = "string_speed")
    private Long string_speed;
    @Column(name = "string_color_type")
    private Long string_color_type;
    @Column(name = "string_color")
    private String string_color;
    @Column(name = "string_timing_type")
    private String string_timing_type;
    @Column(name = "string_timing")
    private String string_timing;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "massagess")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<RstringsEntity> strings = new HashSet<>();
    public MasageEntity() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getString_text() {
        return string_text;
    }

    public void setString_text(String string_text) {
        this.string_text = string_text;
    }

    public Long getString_speed() {
        return string_speed;
    }

    public void setString_speed(Long string_speed) {
        this.string_speed = string_speed;
    }

    public Long getString_color_type() {
        return string_color_type;
    }

    public void setString_color_type(Long string_color_type) {
        this.string_color_type = string_color_type;
    }

    public String getString_color() {
        return string_color;
    }

    public void setString_color(String string_color) {
        this.string_color = string_color;
    }

    public String getString_timing_type() {
        return string_timing_type;
    }

    public void setString_timing_type(String string_timing_type) {
        this.string_timing_type = string_timing_type;
    }

    public String getString_timing() {
        return string_timing;
    }

    public void setString_timing(String string_timing) {
        this.string_timing = string_timing;
    }

    public Set<RstringsEntity> getMassages() {
        return strings;
    }
    public void setTutorials(Set<RstringsEntity> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }
}
```

strings_repo.java

```
package Dyplom.rString.repository;

import Dyplom.rString.entity.RstringsEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface strings_repo extends JpaRepository<RstringsEntity, Long> {
    RstringsEntity findByName(String name);
    RstringsEntity findRstringsEntitiesById(Long string_id);
    List<RstringsEntity> findRstringsEntitiesByMasageEntitiesId(Long massage_id);


}
```

massage_repo.java

```
package Dyplom.rString.repository;

import Dyplom.rString.entity.MasageEntity;
import Dyplom.rString.entity.RstringsEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface massage_repo extends JpaRepository <MasageEntity, Long> {

    MasageEntity findMasageEntitiesById(Long massage_id);
    List<MasageEntity> findMasageEntitiesByRstringsEntitiesId(Long string_id);
    List<MasageEntity> findMasageEntityByRstringsEntityId(Long string_id);

}
```

I don't see the point in showing the controller, since the error occurs elsewhere.

What's I doing wrong? Maybe I need some settings or dependencies? Or I can solve the problem in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the name of the query method: `findMasageEntitiesByRstringsEntitiesId(Long`. You need to use the field name from your entity class, not the class name.

I would try `findMasageEntitiesByStringsId(Long...`. (It's also a bit confusing that you've given the variable one name and the getter method another, not sure if JPA will like that.)

The other methods which returns a list also suffer from the same problem.